# When Ember's mom in Elemental was first seen giving a love reading, were they two guys that she was reading?

Tags: character, analysis, elemental-2023

I was watching the new movie Elemental, but as I watched it, it seemed like that, while Ember's mom was doing a love reading (near the beginning), one of the people she was reading seemed like a man.

Are they both guys? Or does the girl just have a weird voice?

[image: fire couple touching their fingers to the sticks]

Comment: She has quite an unusual, low-pitched voice.

Comment: There's nothing useful in the Audio Description. The roles aren't listed in the final credits and the official subtitles don't identify them by name. The scene doesn't appear in the [*Elemental: Little Golden Book*](https://youtu.be/xTsDULUetaA?si=qOxx6NllylsPBJoI&t=44), [*The Art of Elemental*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrtTnUHFNyk), [*Elemental: A City for Everyone*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAW1LLekHTI), [*Exploring Element City*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJ_u71AbTL4) or [*Elemental: Better Together*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaIWgG9n2OE).

Comment: It's also not shown in [Elemental: A Family's Dream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8xkkURRo1I). I can't think of anywhere else to look; These are all the additional books and materials that we have to date; https://pixarpost.com/2023/03/numerous-elemental-books-revealed.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of them is male, according to the film's official novelisation.

> *"So, are we a match?"* **asked the fire guy.**
>
> [snip]
>
> When Cinder turned back toward the fire couple, they were embracing. She squirted them with the spray bottle *"Save it for the wedding!"*, she spat.
>
> *"Hey"*, **the fire guy sputtered.**

In the film these two lines are not spoken by the same person, but the way it's worded in the novel suggests the two lines were originally intended to be spoken by a single (male) person, so we can probably play safe and presume that this is a heterosexual couple.

---

In the graphic novel , the smaller of the two individuals is rather more feminine-looking and it's the '*fire guy*' who asks the question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's weird, because I remember in the movie, the woman was the one asking the question... but thank you for your time and effort helping to answer my question!

Comment: @TimMcYeah - They seem to have reversed the scene, possibly to give the woman in the wheelchair additional prominence.